# Pivot SQL-Server table with established columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

I've been struggling with this for a while now, in that I cannot find a query that allows for a pivot of one column without a second reference/ID column to pivot on.

My current table looks as depicted:

```
Y1M1 Y1M2  Y1M3   Y1M4   Y1M5
-----------------------------
0    NULL  NULL   NULL   NULL
125  NULL  NULL   NULL   NULL
250  NULL  NULL   NULL   NULL
500  NULL  NULL   NULL   NULL
750  NULL  NULL   NULL   NULL
```

When I would like to pivot to something similar to:

```
Y1M1  Y1M2  Y1M3  Y1M4  Y1M5
-----------------------------
0     125   250   500   750
```

Due in part to the complexity of a pivot statement and part a surprising lack of guides about one-column pivoting the closest query I've written is

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  (SELECT [Y1M1]
   FROM @Result) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
  (MAX([Y1M1])
  FOR [Y1M1]
  IN ([Y1M2],[Y1M3],[Y1Q1],[Y1M4],[Y1M5])) AS PivotTable
```

However, this query returns all NULL values and I cannot add the [Y1M1] column to the IN clause without throwing an error on execution. Likewise, variations of the query using UNPIVOT also have proved difficult to run successfully.

Any advice regarding PIVOT queries would be appreciated

Comment: The IN clause is looking for values (not column names), so 0,125,250, ... etc.

Comment: Do you recommend and specific posts for updating the IN clause to accommodate dynamic values? Alternatively, is there a way to remove the IN clause without throwing an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a field to pivot the values on, see if the sequential order as a derived field works.

```
SELECT Y1M1=[1],Y1M2=[2],Y1M3=[3],Y1M4=[4],Y1M5=[5]
FROM 
  (SELECT Y1M1, RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Y1M1)
   FROM @Result) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Y1M1)
    FOR RN IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
) 
AS PivotTable
```

Comment: Solution works! So, just to make sure I understand: this query requires a supplementary RowNumber (or equivalent) column to pivot on, using the RN to fill the IN clause?

Comment: Yes think of it as this. You gave me the amount of money you made in Spring, Summer, Winter and Fall, but did not specify the season. If the money is ordered by the time you obtained it then we give each value a rank 1,2,3,4 and pivot out on the rank. The value displayed for each rank pushed out is the value that matched the rank in the vertical inner query result.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a CTE or subquery to get to an output like this:

```
**Name  Value**
Y1M1    0
Y1M2    125
Y1M3    250
Y1M4    500
Y1M5    750
```

Then you can just do a regular pivot on that derived table.